# Powershell - Looping through XML

Tags: xml, powershell

I have made this example XML to loop through and I am interested in outputting the product name for each item.

```
<example>
<item>
    <productname>Hoover</productname>
</item>
<item>
    <productname>TV</productname>
</item>
<item>
    <productname>Microwave</productname>
</item>
<item>
    <productname>Computer</productname>
</item>
</example>
```

In my powershell,  I can easily loop through each item, but I am unable to select the contents of "productname" and I am unsure why. Here is my example powershell code:

```
[xml] $xml = Get-Content "./xmlexample.xml"

foreach ($item in $xml.example) {
    Write-Host($item.InnerXML) #Outputs all XML as expected
    Write-Host($item.InnerText) #Outputs the text of all child elements as expected 
    Write-Host($item.productname.InnerText) #Does not output anything
    Write-Host($item.productname.InnerXML) #Does not output anything
}
```

Any help or advice as to why this doesn't work would be appreciated. It's acting like a child element with no further children is not treated the same way.

Comment: Please try `foreach ($item in $xml.example.ChildNodes)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over `$xml.example.ChildNodes` and then the text is just `$item.productname`:

```
PS C:\users\IEUser\Documents> foreach ($item in $xml.example.ChildNodes) {
>>>    Write-Host($item.productname)
>>> }
Hoover
TV
Microwave
Computer
```

Or if you only want `item` elements containing `productname` you can iterate the `item` nodes:

```
PS C:\users\IEUser\Documents> foreach ($item in $xml.example.item) {
>>>    Write-Host($item.productname)
>>> }
Hoover
TV
Microwave
Computer
```

Or just extract an array of strings directly:

```
PS C:\users\IEUser\Documents> $xml.example.item.productname
Hoover
TV
Microwave
Computer
```

Comment: Maybe you assigned something over `$xml` and/or `$item`. My code snippets are direct copy/paste after the `[xml] $xml = Get-Content ".\xmlexample.xml"`

Comment: I think I messed something up. I have your code working now - I think I never went into the 'item' element, which is why it wasn't working for me. Your examples were very clear and useful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Powershell xml maps the leafs of an xml document as properties. Also, similar like in Linq-to-XML, each query may return an array of elements.
So you can write your loop actually like this:

```
[xml]$xml = '<example>
<item>
   <productname>Hoover</productname>
</item>
<item>
   <productname>TV</productname>
</item>
<item>
  <productname>Microwave</productname>
</item>
<item>
  <productname>Computer</productname>
</item>
</example>'
$xml.example.item[1].productname = "Foo"
$xml.example.item.productname | Write-Host
```

Results in:

```
Hoover
Foo
Microwave
Computer
```

'productname' acts like a string property which can be set or retrieved. Therefore it has no further xml methods or properties.

Comment: To be completely accurate, `$xml.example.item.productname` is an array and each of its elements is a string.